# Wheat-free bread with added gluten?

Tags: vital-wheat-gluten

I would like to make wheat-free bread but add gluten (can't eat the high fructans content of the wheat, but can eat gluten). I can't find any recipes that do this. Anyone got any pointers? I was thinking of using standard gluten-free (and therefore wheat-free) flour, then adding wheat gluten. Would this work?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Recipe requests are off topic for this site; you should probably read the Help information to find out more.

Comment: I would consider that a recipe design question, not a recipe request.

Comment: I can point you to keto bread recipes, in case those keywords are new and helpful. I personally buy pre-made vital what gluten bread (from "great low carb bread co") but this is quite common in the keto community so you'll probably be able to find recipes to do it yourself.

Comment: Why do you want to add the gluten back to the bread? Is it about the texture/consistency of the final product? Just thinking it may be easier to go straight wheat-and-gluten free.

Comment: You can simply try Gluten-free breads. You can find many recipes for the same. It might be a better option than removing gluten and then adding it back. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've never found wheat gluten flour that was higher than 80% gluten which is what I use, adding some when I make bread with rye flour. But if you can't eat wheat due to high fructans content, would you still be able to digest the fructan in the other 20%? You wouldnt be adding much gluten flour so the small amount of fructans might be okay.

Rather than buying and using standard gluten-free flour which is quite expensive, why not mix up your own? It's easy to. I've made gluten-free bread a few times for a friend who's since moved. The wheat-free flour mix that I made was rice flour, tapioca flour, potato flour and coconut flour in the ratio 3:3:3:1. You can then add gluten flour to this mix if you still want to try using gluten instead of xanthan gum. Xanthan gum is added to all gluten-free bread flours to help the dough keep its shape while rising. It's not needed if you plan on adding gluten though.

Bread flour is normally 10-13% gluten. Trouble is I don't know if that's by volume or weight. Maybe someone reading this knows and can tell you. If it is by volume, then replacing 2 tablespoons of the flour mix with 2 tablespoons of gluten flour should give you roughly the right gluten content. Hard to be exact as it's possible gluten flours vary in their actual gluten content.

Comment: It's 10-13% protein by weight. "Volume" doesn't really apply because proteins are microscopic and evenly dispersed throughout the flour